# Use "a" or "an" appropriately (pluralization?) when formatting numbers into strings

Tags: ios, uikit, foundation

I'm making an iOS interface that uses sentences like "an 18-minute run" or "a 5-minute walk".

I'd like to use the correct "a" vs "an" article in these strings, but I'm not sure where to start - it feels like a pluralization issue, but I don't know of a good way to handle it.

For example, I'd like something that does this:

```
1 -> a
2 -> a
3 -> a
...
8 -> an
9 -> a
...
18 -> an
...etc
```

Here's an [article on articles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/).

**Is there an available API in Apple's Foundation or UIKit that will help with this?**

Comment: https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm

Comment: Right, I know the grammar rule when I'm reading/writing, but I'm looking for an API to do this. I'll update the question to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure you need an API. If you are only worried about English, the only numbers using "an" are 8, 11, 18, eighty-xxx, eight-hundred xxx, eight-thousand xxx, eleven-thousand xxx, etc. Depending on your expected range of numbers, that's a pretty small set to check for in a little helper function.

Comment: @maddy I hear ya, and that's my current working implementation - I'm more trying to understand if there's a Foundation API that supports this. So far, sounds like there isn't!